# combine get_where and like query codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a 'search' feature unto my website, my query is little bit complicated because it uses 'join', 'like', 'get_where'. Below is what I've tried so far which does not work unfortunately.

```
$business_where['b.active'] = '1';
$business_where['b.deleted'] = '0';
$input = $this->input->get('keyword',TRUE);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join("category c", "c.category_id = b.category_id", "left");
$this->db->order_by('date_created', 'DESC');
$this->db->like('name',$input);
$query = $this->db->get_where('listing_businesses as b', $business_where );

$data['results'] = $query->result();

$this->load->view('elements/header',$data);
$this->load->view('pages/the_nominees', $data );
$this->load->view('elements/footer',$data);
```

The code above gives me an empty result, though it suppose to return some results because the search keyword was correct. Any help, ideas please?

**Update:**

change the code to

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join("category c", "c.category_id = b.category_id", "left");
    $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'DESC');

    $this->db->like('listing_title',$input);
    $query = $this->db->get_where('listing_businesses as b', $business_where );

    $data['page'] = 'nominees';

    $data['results'] = $query->result();
```

it gives me the result that I want but the rest of the results are duplicates. Any ideas, help please?

Comment: what is the value of `$business_where`?

Comment: Updated, please refer above, I just want to know If I'm doing the correct query

Comment: i think you need to use `group_by('xxx')` where xxx is a duplicate field

Comment: what does *but the rest of the results are duplicates* mean ? because i don't see a way of duplicates here - you just join a table where 1 listing has 1 category ...

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for get_where is :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

and in your code u should check a condition in where

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('listing_businesses as b',array ('$business_where' =>some value );
```